# Update autocomplete-list dynamically in Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I want to update the results of the autocomplete component dynamically.

My site should be something like a filter. I got the results of the completeMethod in the autoComplete from the database. If I change some property in the filter the results of the autocomplete completeMethod should also change.

Here is my code of the .xhtml:

```
 <div class="ui-g-5">
        <p:datePicker id="sabDate"  value="#{mainBackingBean.sabDate}" showIcon="true" monthNavigator="true" yearNavigator="true" yearRange="1990:2030" 
                    pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" placeholder="Datum auswaehlen" showButtonBar="true" >
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="acCBV" listener="#{mainBackingBean.sabDateChange}" />
        </p:datePicker>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-4">
        <p:outputLabel for="acCBV" styleClass="filterLabel" value="CBV:" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-5">
        <p:autoComplete id="acCBV" styleClass="autoComplete" value="#{mainBackingBean.cbv}" completeMethod="#{mainBackingBean.completeCbv}" immediate="true" scrollHeight="200" dropdown="true" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The code of the BeanClass:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mainBackingBean")
public class MainBackingBean {
    ...
    public List<String> completeCbv(String statement){

        filter.setCbv(statement);
        return filter.getCbvList();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now the autoComplete got the results of the completeMethod in the start but it never call the method to update the results.

Any suggestions?
Best, Markus

Comment: why the date picker is in the code? what does it affect?
what scope is your mainBakingBean?
please check the server log for any exceptions especially inside /filter/ @markus

Comment: Thanks for you help! The solution was to add @ApplicationScoped in front of  my mainBackingBean.